# How do I parallelize this pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I want something that does that equivalent of

```
var docs = new LinkedList<string>();
for(int i = 0; ; ++i)
{
    string html = client.DownloadString($"http://someforum.com/page?id={i}"); 
    if(html == null)
       break;
    docs.AddLast(html);
}
```

except that would exploit the fact that  `client.DownloadString($"http://someforum.com/page?id={i}");` is a long running task that could be getting run in different threads.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get the HTML from the pages

`"http://someforum.com/page?id=0"`, `"http://someforum.com/page?id=1"`, ...

except that as soon as I don't get a page from `id=m` then I assume any tasks trying to get page `id=n` for some `n>m` will not get a page and can be shut down.

Answer (score 3):

The program you are thinking to make parallel, has a IO call as the main aspect, so its better to use Asynchronous programming using `TaskCompletionSource`, since the `DownloadAsync` methods of `Webclient` returns a `void`. Following is the modified version of `ReadData`:

```
public Task<string> ReadData(int i)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var client = new WebClient();
    string uriString = @"http://someforum.com/page?id=" + i;
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender,args) =>
    {
         tcs.TrySetCanceled();
         tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
         tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uriString));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

**Calling ReadData Asynchronously**

You can preferably do it via an `async` method, which can `await`, till all the download calls return. Also as its multiple `Async` calls so preferably set a limit to `i`, like sync version you cannot be checking the value of each Download and return, all calls are processed together in this case

```
public async Task<LinkedList<string>> ReadDataAsync()
{
var docs = new LinkedList<string>();

List<Task<string>> taskList =  new List<Task<string>>();

for (int i = 0; ; ++i) // Set a limit to i, since you are not running synchronously, so you cannot keep checking which value yields null as result
{
    int localId = i;
    taskList.Add(ReadData(localId));
}

 await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

 // Do Link List processing, if the Task is not cancelled and doesn't have an error, then result can be accessed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel class instead of tasks. Something like this

```
var docs = new LinkedList<string>();
var result = Parallel.For(0, N, n =>
{
    string html = new WebClient().DownloadString($"http://someforum.com/page?id={n}"); 
    if(html != null)
    {
        lock(docs)
        {
            docs.AddLast(html);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov yes, master! :-)

Comment: Using Parallel API is a very bad decision in this case, since thread a no role to play in the IO call, it will just wait for download to return, once dispatched. In fact adding the `lock` makes the solution even further inefficient, as it will make all the threads wait. Async-Await is the best solution, since it doesn't invoke any thread from the pool

Comment: @user7127000 forget about WebClient and use HttpWebClient instead.